# I have Tried this solution for counting paths between two vertices using dfs. but have some doubts in my solution. pls have a look

Tags: c++, graph, path, tree

i have created two functions for finding paths between two vertices in a adjacency matrix.
first function countPath run for each edge of source vertex;

```
    void countPath(int s,int d){
        int count=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < V;i++){
            
            if(visited[i]==0&&adj_mat[s][i]==1){
                cout << s << " ";
                searchForNode(i, d, &count);
            }
        }
        cout << count << endl;
    }
```

second function searchForNode  searches the path for each edge of source node to destination vertex;

```
    bool searchForNode(int i,int k,int *c){
        if(i==k){
            cout << "f" << i << endl;
            return true;
        }
        int cnt = 0;
        visited[i] = 1;
        bool flag = false;
        cout << i << " ";
        for (int j = 0; j < V;j++){
            if(visited[j]==0&&adj_mat[i][j]==1){
                if(searchForNode(j,k,c)){
                    flag = true;
                    cnt++;
                    // return true;
                }
            }
        }
        if(flag==true){
            *c = *c + cnt;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Please be more specific about your problems than "have some doubts".

Comment: Where is `visited` defined? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: does the code produce the wrong result? Crash? Run too slowly? not compile?

Comment: in this question both adj_mat and visited are defined globally. this code is running fine but for some cases it is returning wrong count.mostly for those paths which can be reached in multiple ways